# Error While converting Json string to json Array

Tags: android, json, android-listview

I am doing an application which need to populate the listview from mysql database and i  referred the tutorial. But i am getting the error message "invalid Response"which is from the catch block of json string . can anyone have a look on this and help me  [Tutorial Link](http://www.semurjengkol.com/populating-android-listview-with-json-based-data-fetched-from-mysql-server-using-php/)

```
 try {
        // convert json string to json array
        JSONArray aJson = new JSONArray(sJson);
        // create apps list
        List<Application> apps = new ArrayList<Application>();

        for(int i=0; i<aJson.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject json = aJson.getJSONObject(i);
            Application app = new Application();
            app.setTitle(json.getString("app_title"));
            app.setTotalDl(Long.parseLong(json.getString("total_dl")));
            app.setRating(Integer.parseInt(json.getString("rating")));
            app.setIcon(json.getString("icon"));

            // add the app to apps list
            apps.add(app);
        }

        //notify the activity that fetch data has been complete
        if(listener != null) listener.onFetchComplete(apps);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        msg = "Invalide Response";
        if(listener != null) listener.onFetchFailure(msg);
        return;
    }
```

Comment: Post your code so we can help you. And the stack trace.

Comment: The code is same as in the tutorial link thats why i didnt post the code . :(

Comment: And the Exception? In which line is failing?

Comment: Can you log out the exception?

Comment: am getting the JSONException message " Invalide Response"

Comment: Yeah, thats because it is hardcoded in your catch block, but not necessarily the real error

Comment: The error message is "Value <html><body>script of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONArray"

Comment: That is because the response you are receiving when you are trying to create the JSOnArray in this line JSONArray aJson = new JSONArray(sJson); is not a JSONArray. Reading what you said, you probably will be receiving an HTML page, what is not a JSONArray.

Comment: <html><body><script type="text/javascript" src="/aes.js" ></script><script>function toNumbers(d)....................................................................................................................."http://busmate.byethost7.com/apps.php?ckattempt=1";</script><noscript>This site requires Javascript to work, please enable Javascript in your browser or use a browser with Javascript support</noscript></body></html>

getting Something likethis on "sJson"

Comment: That is obviously not a JSONArray...

Comment: Then what will be the reason for getting this string instead of Json Array @Fustigador

Comment: The server side is not set properly. Since it is an internet example, I assume you have no access to it...but your code looks ok.